# How to detect EOF for two source files in loop condition?

Tags: conditionals, loops

For a critical edition in two languages, my `Main.tex` file has a loop that:

1. reads a line from first source file
2. reads a line from second source file
3. outputs the lines with the `\chunks` command
4. uses `\ifeof0` to control `\loop` by detecting EOF of first source file

A better `\loop` would check EOF for both source files. However, TeXstudio will not compile `\ifeof0` and `\ifeof1` in the loop condition. Any advice?

---

Source files and example code follow.

Please assume source files with these contents.

`LeftPageParagraphs.tex`:

```
This is paragraph 1 from LeftPageParagraphs.tex file.

This is paragraph 2 from LeftPageParagraphs.tex file.
```

RightPageParagraphs.tex:

```
This is paragraph 1 from RightPageParagraphs.tex file.

This is paragraph 2 from RightPageParagraphs.tex file.
```

An annotated minimum working example of the problem:

```
% Test: read lines from files.

\documentclass[openany]{book}

\usepackage{paracol}  % Parallel columns package
\usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage{ifthen}

% The \chunks command outputs two parallel paragraphs 
% to left and right columns on facing pages.
\newcommand\chunks[2]{%
    \begin{leftcolumn*}
        {#1}%
    \end{leftcolumn*}%
    \begin{rightcolumn}
        {#2}%
    \end{rightcolumn}%
    }

\begin{document}

    % Algorithm:
    % Read a line (a paragraph) from input stream 0.
    % Read a line (a paragraph) from input stream 1.
    % Output line to left column on left page.
    % Output line to right column on right page.    
    % Detect end-of-file in input stream 0.

    % PASS with condition: \ifeof0
    % FAIL with condition: { \( \ifeof0 \and \ifeof1 \) }
    % ERROR: Incomplete \ifeof; all text was ignored after line 49.
    
    % Open files in input streams 0 and 1.
    \openin0 = LeftPageParagraphs
    \openin1 = RightPageParagraphs
    
    \begin{paracol}[1]*{2}  
        
        \loop 
        { 
            \read0 to \inputL  
            \read1 to \inputR
  
            \chunks
                {\inputL}
                {\inputR}
        }       
        \( \ifeof0 \and \ifeof1 \) % <-- ERROR
        \repeat

    \end{paracol}
    
    % Close files in input streams 0 and 1.
    \closein0
    \closein1
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11):

in

```
\( \ifeof0 \and \ifeof1 \)
```

`\(` and `\)`  are commands for *typesetting* math, not for evaluating logical expressions

`\and` is a command used by `\maketitle` for separating authors

`\ifeof0` accesses stream 0 which is reserved by LaTeX as part of `\IFFileExists` , `filecontents` and other file related constructs.

replace streams 0 and 1 by two allocated streams

```
\newread\streamL
\newread\streamR
```

and combine the tests for example by having a new `\if..` command used in the loop

`\newif\ifcontinue`

```
\loop
...
\continuetrue
\ifeof\streamL
   \ifeof\streamR
      \continuefalse
   \fi
\fi
\ifcontinue
\repeat
```

Which will continue the loop until both streams hit eof.

Comment: Perhaps clarify that `\(`, `\)` and `\and` can be used for logical statements only in the first argument of `\ifthenelse`?

Comment: @JosephWright I try to forget about `\ifthenelse`

Comment: @JosephWright ah I just now saw the related [question on meta](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8913/submitted-answer-has-incorrect-statements-about-tex-but-code-solves-problem)